# web2py: how to detect when an LOAD component has loaded via ajax?

Tags: ajax, web2py, asynccallback

I'm injecting a component into my web2py page using `{{=LOAD(...)}}` as described at http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/12/components-and-plugins#LOAD, but I need to fire off some javascript once the component is loaded. Normally if something is loaded via ajax, there is a success callback. How can I set one of this via `{{=LOAD(...)}}` in web2py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to set `response.js` in the controller of the component:

```
def mycomponent():
    response.js = 'alert("mycomponent just loaded");'
    return dict()
```

Alternatively, you could simply include a `<script>` tag directly in the component itself, which will execute when the component is loaded.

Finally, whenever a web2py Ajax call completes, an `ajax:complete` event is fired. So, you could set up an event handler and check whether the Ajax response is a component:

```
  $(document).on('ajax:complete', function(e, xhr, status) {
    if (xhr.getResponseHeader('web2py-component-content')) {
      alert('A component just loaded.');
    }
  });
```

Note that the presence of the `web2py-component-content` header indicates that the Ajax response is a component.

The only downside of this last approach is that the event handler will be triggered *before* the content of the component is added to the DOM, so if the event handler takes long to run, it may noticeably delay the appearance of the component content.

Comment: I'm trying to modify the DOM (highlight a row) after the LOAD on the client side. The response.js works ok, unless the component view is cached. In that case, it is not sent. The ajax:complete does get trigger, but as you mentioned, it run *before* the content is added to the DOM. Which undoes my modifications. Is there a way to modify the content before it's applied?