# Web2py - How to determine end of load control after ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, web2py, jquery-chosen

I run a ajax call that updates interpolated value as a fully built selectbox element.

I would like to transform the created/returned selectbox into a chosen selectbox **once it has finished fully loading** otherwise it reverts back to a regular selectbox.

I have tried:

- Listening to 'DOMSubtreeModified'(and other similar events) and then activating chosen lines but, these run too often and I have to know when the selectbox with all options are **fully initiated**. I can force initiation on each change, it's terrible - resource consuming and just plain wrong.
- Initiate some callback on ajax return('ajax:complete' event) but, again - this does **not** guarantee the html controls are fully initiated as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40685620/web2py-how-to-detect-when-an-load-component-has-loaded-via-ajax) (and tested).
- I've tried to set a onload event for the select control.

Main lines of code:

JavaScript call:

```
ajax('{{=URL('controller_name', 'func_name')}}', ['param1'], 'target_div');
```

Python controller returns(this returns a select control with option objects initiated in it and overrides the target_div inner html):

```
return SELECT(distinct_values, _id = 'selectbox_id' , _multiple = 'true' , _class='SelectBoxSingleDisabled');
```

Looking for a web2py oriented solution. No brute force/hacky stuff if possible. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options (the first two are suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40687171/440323)):

1. In the controller, add the Chosen initialization code to `response.js` -- this will be executed after the returned HTML is added to the DOM.
2. Add the Chosen initialization code to a script element after the select element:

   ```
   CAT(SELECT(distinct_values, _id = 'manual_group_selectbox' , _multiple = 'true' ,
              _class='SelectBoxSingleDisabled'),
       SCRIPT('[Chosen code]'))
   ```
3. The third argument to the `ajax()` function can be a Javascript function that takes the data returned by the server. So, you could write a function that adds the returned HTML to the DOM and then initializes Chosen:

   ```
   ajax(
     '{{=URL('controller_name', 'func_name')}}', ['param1'],
     function(html) {
       [add html to DOM]
       [initialize Chosen]
     }
   );
   ```
4. Set up a jQuery `.ajaxSuccess()` event handler, which should run after the `ajax()` function updates the DOM.

Comment: I seems option 2 doesn't guarantee DOM elements are added :/

Comment: Hmm, I tried option 2 specifically with Chosen, and it works for me (at least in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Edge).

Comment: the chosen exists but not the options inside of it - for options 1 & 2

Comment: what I'm trying to do is edit each option returned. Do you know a way I can create these in the controller SELECT line instead of giving a list for options?

Comment: Again, it works for me. Not quite sure what you mean by editing the returned options. Maybe post a new question with your exact code and more detail about what you are trying to achieve.